# comparar datos Time de BBDD con datos POST PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Tengo la siguiente función a la que le paso dos parámetros por POST mediante un input type time de un formulario:

```
//inicio propuesto y fin propuesto son la hora de comienzo y finalizacion de la reunion.
    public function comprobar_inicio_fin($inicioPropuesto, $finPropuesto){

//hago la consulta para comprobar en todas las reuniones si ya hay reuniones con alguna de esas horas 
    $consulta=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM reunion");
    $consulta->execute();
    $reunion = new Reunion();
    $reunionDao = new ReunionDAO();

//llamo el metodo que me lista todas las reuniones y hago un bucle para recorrer sus columnas inicio y fin
    $listaReuniones = $reunionDao->todasLasReuniones();
    foreach($listaReuniones as $reunion){

        $inicio = $reunion->getInicio();
        $fin = $reunion->getFin();

//Aquí formateo las horas que le paso para que puedan compararse con el formato HH:MM:SS que tienen en la BBDD.
        $inicioFormateado = new DateTime($inicioPropuesto);
        $finFormateado = new DateTime($finPropuesto);
        $inicioFormateado->format('H:i:s').'<br>';
        $finFormateado->format('H:i:s').'<br>';

//Ahora las comparo.
   if ($inicio == $inicioFormateado && $fin == $finFormateado){

    echo $inicio.' soy la hora de inicio de la BBDD <br>';
    echo $inicioFormateado->format('H:i:s').' soy la hora de inicio que pasas por el input <br>';
    echo $fin.' soy la hora de fin de la BBDD <br>';
    echo $finFormateado->format('H:i:s').' soy la hora de fin que pasas por el input <br>';
    echo "estoy en el if que compara inicio y fin <br>";

    } else {
        echo $inicio.' soy la hora de inicio de la BBDD <br>';
        echo $inicioFormateado->format('H:i:s').' soy la hora de inicio que pasas por el input <br>';
        echo $fin.' soy la hora de fin de la BBDD <br>';
        echo $finFormateado->format('H:i:s').' soy la hora de fin que pasas por el input <br>';
        echo "estoy en el else que compara inicio y fin<br>";

        echo '<br>';
    }
    }
}
```

El problema es que siempre entra en el else, aunque las horas coincidan. He hecho una prueba metiendo como hora de inicio las 13:00 y fin las 14:00. Después he hecho un echo de todo y me devuelve esto:

13:00:00 soy la hora de inicio de la BBDD

13:00:00 soy la hora de inicio que pasas por el input

14:00:00 soy la hora de fin de la BBDD

14:00:00 soy la hora de fin que pasas por el input

estoy en el else que compara inicio y fin.

¿Qué está pasando? ¿El formato DateTime no puede compararse con el type time?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resulto. Había que formatear también los datos de la BBDD.

```
//Esto iría justo después de las líneas $inicio = $reunion->getInicio();$fin = $reunion->getFin();

        $inicio = new DateTime($inicio);
        $fin = new DateTime($fin);
        $inicio->format('H:i:s');
        $fin->format('H:i:s');
```

Ahora ya podemos compararlo!